# FIFO Input Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, input, queue, operator-overloading, fifo

Currently learning C++, I am trying to create two classes `Bit` and `BitBuffer` to work with bit streams.

My `Bit` class is composed by one `unsigned char`.
The principle is to send `Bit`s to one `BitBuffer` object and when 8 `Bit`s are in one `BitBuffer` object, I flush the buffer.

I am trying to overload the input operator for the `BitBuffer` class because I would like to be able to write the following commands:

```
Bit x;
BitBuffer buffer;
x >> buffer;
```

I wrote one `enqueue` method so I think I should just call this method in my overloaded operator. However, when I type these commands now, Xcode tells me "Invalid operands to binary expression".

I tried to understand this error but can't figure out why Xcode tells me that I use a function as variable.

Any help would be more than welcome,
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Xcode has an advantage, it has the code. How do you expect anyone to guess what's going on from your description?

Comment: I thought I gave enough information but will post the complete code if it can help

Comment: Make sure you remove anything that is not necessary to demostrate the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure there is an `operator>>` defined somewhere that takes a `Bit` as the first argument and a `BitBuffer` as the second. More likely though, you'll want to reverse those arguments and write the expression like:

```
buffer << x;
```

because then you could also chain multiple bits into the buffer:

```
buffer << x << y << z;
```

If you have an written an operator on the `BitBuffer` class like this:

```
class BitBuffer {
public:
    BitBuffer& operator<<(const Bit& b) {
        // do your work here
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I always saw the `<<` operator overloaded as `friend istream& operator>> (istream&, myType&);` so I did not know that it was possible to overload it as you did. I'll try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: Writing the operator as a friend function (with, in your case, signature `BitBuffer& operator<<(BitBuffer&, const Bit&)` is another option, and arguably a better choice (though I find it easier to first write it as I've shown in my answer, then move it out as a friend function).